# Symfony access control on route with parameter

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

How do I grant IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY access to a route which includes a parameter?

I tried inducing the parameter in the access control path (see below) but got the exception: `The file "/vagrant/app/config/security.yml" does not contain valid YAML.`

Security.yml

```
access_control:
      - { path: ^/api/profile/img/{id}, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [GET] }
      - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_API }
```

Profile.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/profile/img/{id}", name="profile_img_get", requirements={"id": "\d+"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getAction($id, Request $request)
{}
```

Comment: `path: ^/api/profile/img/, roles:...`

Comment: access_control path accepts regex